# How to includ all values from both tables? Group-Concat and other values

Tags: android, database, sqlite, group-concat, subquery

In short, I have provided the data, and the current results, please tell me what to do to make the last step. Using SQLite please.

== Written explanation ==

Want to concatenate values from table A using table B, but then display all results from table A even the ones that have no value in table B. I have tried a whole bunch of variations, and I am truly stuck.

Tables:

*user_tables*

```
_id         table_name  table_version  table_status
----------  ----------  -------------  ------------
1           addresses   1              1
2           jobs        1              1
3           people      1              1
4           phones      1              1
```

*user_tables_depends*

```
_id         user_table_id  user_table_depend_id
----------  -------------  --------------------
1           1              2
2           1              3
3           2              1
4           2              4
5           4              2
```

Current query:

```
SELECT table_name, table_version, table_status, 
     GROUP_CONCAT(dependName, ', ') AS table_dependencies 
FROM user_tables JOIN 
    (SELECT user_table_id, table_name AS dependName 
     FROM user_tables_depends, user_tables 
     WHERE user_tables._id = user_table_depend_id) 
WHERE user_tables._id = user_table_id 
GROUP BY table_name
```

Query Result:

```
table_name  table_version  table_status  table_dependencies
----------  -------------  ------------  ------------------
addresses   1              1             jobs, people
jobs        1              1             addresses, phones
phones      1              1             jobs
```

Desired result:

```
table_name  table_version  table_status  table_dependencies
----------  -------------  ------------  ------------------
addresses   1              1             jobs, people
jobs        1              1             addresses, phones
people      1              1             
phones      1              1             jobs
```

Note: please don't worry about what the values are, they are dummy data, I just need the query to work as desired in SQLite please. Thanks in advance, cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what [outer joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Outer_join) are for.
And you should use proper join syntax (with `ON`):

```
SELECT ...
FROM user_tables LEFT JOIN 
    (...)
    ON user_tables._id = user_table_id
GROUP BY ...
```

Comment: aaaah wow, I thought I still had a decent grip on SQL, this is embracing, can't believe I forgot the basics. In any case, thank you sir for the help, and it works like a charm!

Comment: should the operator `+` be used. just for clarification. was just going through one of the books oracle sql it says the + operator has the effect of creating one or more null rows to which one or more rows from nondeficient table can be joined.

Comment: @Raghunandan Using `+` for outer joins is outdated Oracle-specific syntax. Since version 9i, Oracle supports SQL joins.